# Why do I get fpermissive for declaration the following function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Under exercise 6.40 of C++ Primer, I am getting -fpermissive error for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string &word, const string &ending = "s");

int main()
{
    string input;

    cout << "Success:" << make_plural(2, "Success", "es") << endl;
    cout << "Failure:" << make_plural(2, "Failure") << endl;

    return 0;
}

string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string &word, const string &ending = "s")
{
    return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}
```

I am used to prototyping the function before the main function first before declaring the function after the main function. However, I am getting the following error from G++ compiler:

> error: default argument given for parameter 3 of 'std::string make_plural(size_t, const string&, const string&)' [-fpermissive]

Would like to know why this happened.

Comment: -fpermissive is a compiler flag; it is not an error message. Post the actual message.

Comment: Drop the second `= "s"`.

Comment: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of 'std::string make_plural(size_t, const string&, const string&)' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @TruthOrDare -- now **read** the message, starting at the beginning. Yes, T.C.'s comment is right, but the real issue is how to figure this out for yourself.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the feedback. I always thought that in the declaration of the functions, the default arguments have to be included even though the functions have already been prototyped.

Comment: That said, would really want to know why in the declaration of the function, the default argument should not be included if the function has already been prototyped.

Comment: Your problem is that you have a default parameter in the function *definition*, but it should only appear in the function *declaration* (all terms that can be looked up.)

Comment: You're not allowed to repeat a default argument. For ordinary functions that means putting default arguments in the prototype in the header file, and leaving them out of the definition. Same thing here: once the compiler has seen the default argument, that's it: no repetition allowed. If the code did not have the prototype, but instead had the function definition where the prototype currently is, then you'd put the default argument in the function definition.